# File.listFiles returns NULL

Tags: java

I'm calling `File.listFiles()` in my Java app and I'm getting a `null` even though there are multiple files in the folder.  If I run my app from the debugger, everything works.  I'm not sure what's going on here.  I would guess that maybe when running my app outside the debugger, I'm loading a JAR file that's conflicting w/Java File somehow.

Any idea what might be going wrong?
Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
File searchDirectory = new File(aSearchPath);
File[] files = searchDirectory.listFiles();
```

Nothing complex here.  I should also mention that I'm running as a service when I fail.

Comment: Please show your code, otherwise it will be very hard to tell what might be wrong with it. Are you using a relative directory name, and is the current directory different when you run it outside the debugger?

Comment: Side note: consider to use the NIO.2 File API instead of the legacy java.io.File class

Comment: When you're not running with the debugger, the current dir is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: Check folder permissions ,even that could be the possibilities of *NULL*.

Comment: It's the folder permissions.  When running as a service, I don't have read access to the folder.  When debugging I do.  I'm using the same login credentials for both.

Comment: @Mike_G: you should probably post your last comment as an answer (yes, it is perfectly acceptable to post an answer to your own question).

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the folder permissions. When running as a service, I don't have read access to the folder. When debugging I do. I'm using the same login credentials for both.